# How to check instantiated class attributes types?

Tags: python, object, types, attributes, instance

I'm trying to check if the object I instantiated basically instantiates sub-objects, so that I can in turn continue this way until I finish inspecting / error checking input / filling in my object.  The goal is to fill the information of that object without knowing what the attributes are as they are auto-generated by other code, so they are subject to change without notice.  I'm trying to do it using a recursive function.  It might be a bit clearer with an example:

```
### content of B.py:
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Ba = ''
        self.Bb = 0


### content of A.py
from B import B

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = B()
        self.Aa = ''
        self.Ab = False


### content of SDK.py
from A import A
primitiveTypes = (int, str, bool, type(None))

class G:
    def createIt(self, **options)
        fillMe = A()
        fillMe = self.fillWithData(fillMe, options)
        #Do stuff with fillMe (post in JSON format to REST API...)

    def fillWithData(self, obj, options)
        for a in dir(obj):
            if not callable(a) and not a.startswith('_'):
                if isinstance(a, primitiveTypes):
                    obj.__dict__.update({a: options.get(a)})
                else:
                    #This never gets executed because isinstance always returns true -> because it evaluates A.B as type string instead of being of type B
                    obj.__dict__.update({a: self.fillWithData(a, options)})

### content of test.py
from SDK import G

g = G()
g.createIt(Aa='Aa', Ab=True, Ba='Ba', Bb=1) #Make correct input succeed
g.createIt(Aa=1, Ab='', Ba=None, Bb=False) #Make incorrect input fail
```

EDIT: I removed the return statement, thanks for clearing my doubts on that.

To explain why I need all of these different files; I am currently writing an SDK so that people can use it to interact with a REST API (creating users, logging in, adding stuff, modifying stuff, deleting stuff - stuff like roles, permissions, etc.) So we have code which is in C# defining the models and enums (no methods), which is translated to python by a code generator. In the example above, the models would be A.py and B.py. I import them into the SDK (G.py), and so I have test.py to use the SDK methods.

So the problem is: isinstance is always returning true - because it thinks the object b is of type String when it should really be of type B.

Comment: You don't need the `return obj` in `G.fillWithData()` because all you do with the return value is assign it to the local variable named `fillMe` in `G.creatIt()` which doesn't nothing with it (so it's discarded). It's unclear what's correct about one but not the other in the last two lines of code in your question. Please [edit] you question and describe what's correct and what's wrong with the results in each case.

Comment: @martineau actually, `self.fillWithData(a, options)}` is called recursively, and the return value will be used, in the `else` body of `fillWithData`, although, as you say, `fillMe` is not used, so it should probably be an instance variable? Or maybe all of `G` doesn't need to be a class at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Even if called recursively, the ultimate return value isn't used by the initial caller.

Comment: Why are you iterating over `dir` to begin with? Why not `vars` or `__dict__` directly for that matter?

Comment: @martineau yeah, although, I suspect that is a typo or a bug, because then the whole thing is pointless

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I'm wondering about it now, too—which is part of why I asked what are correct results and what are not (what's the goal and how is it failing).

Comment: @martineau I cleared up a few points in the original post. Hopefully it should help, but ultimately, what I do with fillMe is not important. I need 'fillWithData()' to return a filled dictionnary (and their sub-dictionaries) so that I can just send it as JSON to a REST API.  The problem is with isinstance() always evaluating the contents of the objects as string (even though for example they should be of bool class or B class type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a couple of points. First, instead of making a tuple of "primitive types" (note, Python *doesn't have primitive types*) it makes more sense to enumerate the types you *want to handle*, so:

```
In [1]: class B:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.Ba = ''
   ...:         self.Bb = 0
   ...:

In [2]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.B = B()
   ...:         self.Aa = ''
   ...:         self.Ab = False
   ...:

In [3]: registered_types = A, B
```

Second, there is no need for a class `G`, it doesn't hold any state, and just complicates things. If your actual use-case would be improved by being a class, go ahead and adapt it, but I'm going to use just a plain function for the sake of clarity:

```
In [5]: SENTINEL = object()

In [6]: def initialize(obj, **options):
    ...:     for name, subobj in vars(obj).items():
    ...:         if isinstance(subobj, registered_types):
    ...:             filled = initialize(subobj, **options)
    ...:             setattr(obj, name, filled)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             val = options.get(name, SENTINEL)
    ...:             if val is not SENTINEL:
    ...:                 setattr(obj, name, val)
    ...:     return obj
    ...:
```

Note, I use `vars` which checks the instance attributes of the obj, all `vars(obj)` does is return `obj.__dict__`, which is what you want, instead of checking `if x.startswith('_')` etc with what is returned by `dir` (which isn't really meant to be used in production but more for debugging). Also, I iterate over the *items* of `vars`, since that (and `dir`) return a `dict` object, and iterating directly over it iterates over the keys, which are always *strings* which is what you were dealing with before. Also note, I create an arbitrary `SENTINEL` object just to check against instead of `None`, which may be a valid target. Also, I use `setattr` instead of the uglier `obj.__dict__.update(...)` construction.

Finally, the results:

```
In [7]: a = A()

In [8]: a = initialize(a, Aa='Aa', Ab=True, Ba='Ba', Bb=1)

In [9]: a.Aa, a.Ab, a.B.Ba, a.B.Bb
Out[9]: ('Aa', True, 'Ba', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did think of trying it that way too.  Although, I think the problem will still arise. i.e. isinstance() will always evaluate attributes as string, and not registered_types.  I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, the key to solving this was really to use the value and not the key (sounds so obvious put that way now lol) Here is how we solved it in the end on our side:

```
def fillWithData(self, obj, options):
keysToDelete = []
for name, subObj in vars(obj).items():
    if isinstance(subObj, primitiveTypes):
        obj.__dict__.update({name: options.get(name)})
        if obj.__dict__[name] is None: #To remove keys with empty values later
            keysToDelete.append(name)
    elif not isinstance(subObj, types.FunctionType) and not isinstance(subObj, Enum) and not name.startswith('_'):
        obj.__dict__.update({name: self.fillData(subObj, options)})
for k in keysToDelete: #Remove keys with empty values
    del obj.__dict__[k]
return obj
```

Next step... Cleaning up this thing so I don't actually fill in the object with null values and then Delete them afterwards... ;) -> Maybe in another question in the future hehe :P

Comment: Yes, I was about to responsd to the comment you left on my answer regarding the keys/strings issue :). One suggestion, as a matter of style, I think it looks cleaner to use the builtin functions like `getattr`, `setattr`, and `delattr` instead of manipulating `obj.__dict__` directly, it is more readable IMO as well.

Comment: Yes thanks I actually changed it in my actual code 